# I am looking for a Sci-fi short story, about a woman that finds a lonely alien left on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I once heard a radio dramatization of a short story about a woman that finds an alien left on Earth - if I remember it correctly, for exploration and for reporting his findings. She then starts to talk and learn from him that he has been stranded on Earth for a very long period of time, having lived among many of our history periods and recounting first hand his interchange with people from those eras. One name I *kind of* remember from the story is Nicholas.

Comment: How long ago did you hear it on the radio, and in what country?

Comment: I heard it last year in the US. It was on a podcast episode, that I also can't remember the name, nor how I got to it. I checked the ones I subscribe to, but I can't find anything on episodes descriptions that match this plot.